# Парсинг при помощи JSOUP Java

Tags: java, jsoup

Хочу спарсить код с сайта DNS-Shop, но в файл куда сохраняю код, получаю совсем не тот HTML код, что я делаю не так?

```
    String path = "https://www.dns-shop.ru/";
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(path)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582")
            .referrer("http://www.google.com")
            .timeout(9000)
            .get();

    File f = new File("data/index.html");
    
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(f);

    writer.write(document.toString());
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
```

На выходе получаю лишь 1 скрипт.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Скорее всего основной контент сайта грузится после загрузки HTML кода, с помощью JavaScript. В таком случае JSOUP вам не поможет, надо использовать сложный в освоении и использовании Selenium - виртуальный браузер, который дождётся отработки всех скриптов, которые заполнят исходный HTML контентом.